# tunnel from localhost to public: best solution

Tags: localhost, ngrok, tunneling

I'm currently using localtunnel to expose my localhost to the internet. But localtunnel is sometimes down and it fails when sending large(r) files.

I used ngrok before but this is too expensive for what I need it for.

I need one fixed (sub)domain, eg. tunnel.mydomain.com that is connected to http://localhost:3000. Always the same port.

I have nginx as a reverse proxy on my server, but does anyone know a piece of software (I have a ubuntu 20.04 vps) I can use to connect/tunnel my localhost to this server?

Comment: The use case you have written is not fully detailed, I recommend checking this: https://github.com/anderspitman/awesome-tunneling